# htaccess 301 поддомен

Tags: .htaccess

Имеется ссылка www.lb.domen.ru которая открывает через .htaccess страницу /company/domen.php?ELEMENT_ID=69324

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lb\.domen\.ru$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ company/domen.php?ELEMENT_ID=69324
```

---

как правильно сделать редирект если он перешел www.lb.domen.ru/company/ или другую ссылку, т.е нужно чтобы по домену www.lb.domen.ru открывалась только одна страница, другие перенаправлять на основной домен.

```
пробую так, не работает
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domen.ru$ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lb\.domen\.ru$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/?$
RewriteRule .* company/domen.php?ELEMENT_ID=69324 [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.lb\.domen\.ru$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^ELEMENT_ID=69324$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/company\/domen.php$
RewriteRule .* http://domen.ru? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: нет не работает...

Comment: @kotdg, строчку `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/company\/domen.php$` изменил, каталог `company` не был прописан. На локалхосте проверил, работает.

Comment: точно) работает, спасибо